# laravel get data with pop up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to create a form that can get data and select it from pop up. currently, I have 2 sample data record on my database
the problem is, when I was click the select button at the first record, the button is succesfully called the jquery and filled the form, but when I selected second data, the button doesn't select the jquery script.

here my html pop up

```
<div id="search-form" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h4 class="blue bigger">Service</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body overflow-visible">
    <table id="sample-table-1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Service</th>
                <th class="hidden-480">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach ($service as $service)

            <tr>
                <td>{{ $service->service_name }}</td>

                <td>
                    <div class="hidden-phone visible-desktop btn-group">
                        <form method="get">
                            <a class="btn btn-mini btn-info" id="selected_search" onclick="" data-dismiss="modal" svc-id="{{$service->id}}">
                                <i class="icon-check"></i>
                            </a>
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            @endforeach
        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
```

and here my jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#selected_search').on('click', function(e){
    alert("test");
    var id = $('#selected_search').attr('svc-id');
    $.get("{{ url('customer/service')}}/"+id, function(data){
        console.log(id);
        console.log(data);
        $('#service').empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, element){
            $('#service').val(element.service_name);
            $('#service_id').val(element.id);
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
```

and here my laravel controller

```
public function getservice($id){
    $service = Service::find($id);

    return response()->json([$service], 200);
}
```

Comment: Your id `selected_search` should be unique. May be adding index behind this.

Comment: thanks, its working now